# Aligning Main Navigation Product Categories

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I'm using the storefront theme with wordpress, and for the life of me, I can't align the menu items text into the center.

Here is the code I've used so far:

```
.main-navigation ul {
   line-height: 7;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
  border-right: 1px solid #ff63b1;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.main-navigation ul.nav-menu li a {
   padding: 1em 1em;
 }
```

I used the line: text-align: center; with all these but no difference.

Its worth noting, that I used product categories instead of normal menu items here as I found it more useful. Website: http://cutepinkboutique.com if you want to check the code for the main navigation

Here what it looks like so far: [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17dLX.png)

Im banging my head against the wall and can't figure this out. Any help would be great.

Comment: you mean right now is going in left side and you want in center

Comment: please upvote I hope it is useful to you thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS

```
#menu-charlies-top-menu {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You was right the first time. I just added

    .main-navigation ul.nav-menu li a {
      padding: 1em 1em;
      padding-left: 35px;
    }

Comment: can you please upvot me

Answer (score 0):

The answer is but may vary for others:

```
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu li a { 
  padding: 1em 1em; 
  padding-left: 35px; 
}
```

I was looking at the menu items direction (right, left) wrongly.